# Dyno won't show up when I push Procfile to master to deploy the app

Tags: node.js, git, heroku, worker, procfile

When trying to deploy my app; (an app for posting 18,982 screenshots to Twitter with a twitterbot I made, trying to run it in the background), I use Windows Command Prompt and I utilize node for pushing code to the master of my app but it I keep getting an error message and my dyno won't show up (even though the Procfile I made includes `worker: node server.js`

Here is the error message whenever I try to push to master.

```
F:\xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx>git push heroku master
Enumerating objects: 18996, done.
Counting objects: 100% (18996/18996), done.
Delta compression using up to 12 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (18988/18988), done.
Writing objects: 100% (18996/18996), 4.38 GiB | 108.26 MiB/s, done.
Total 18996 (delta 6), reused 18992 (delta 5)
remote:
remote: !       Size of checkout and restored submodules exceeds 1 GB. Reduce size and try pushing again.
remote:
To https://git.heroku.com/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.git
 ! [remote rejected]   master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.git'
```

I followed instructions from these tutorials:

- [Tutorial blog](https://botwiki.org/resource/tutorial/random-image-tweet/#creating-a-twitter-app)
- [Video Tutorial](https://youtu.be/DwWPunpypNA)

Comment: Are you pushing binaries file?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not in your code.

The problem is that you are trying to upload code which exceeds 1GB....

> Size of checkout and restored submodules **exceeds 1 GB**. Reduce size and try pushing again.

**Heroku limit your size to 500MB**

Comment: Is there a way i can upload the 4.38GB code? Like at all? Maybe an alternative?

Comment: You can use a paid service - https://elements.heroku.com/addons/bucketeer